# Where is statement counter incremented for reporting coverage within Go source code?

Tags: go, open-source

I am looking into the Golang source code and want to understand how does it calculate coverage. I understand that each block of code has it's own statement counter; however, where is that statement counter being incremented? 
Here is a link for the cover.go: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/cover/cover.go

Comment: // incCounterStmt returns the expression: __count[23]++.
func incCounterStmt(f *File, counter string) string {
 return fmt.Sprintf("%s++", counter)
}

Answer (score 0):

Realized that you are unable to see where the counters are incremented;; the counters are boolean statements at the end of each block of code and are set to true/false during buildtime.